# How can I transfer the rig from different model?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, error

I am using a animset from Weapon Master in my project, everything is doing fine and I would like to replace the default character, I tried to drag it in place but the rig doesn't seems doing right, I wanna keep the animation in these model, what can I do? Thanks a lot.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Switch your armature to Edit mode and move the bones heads and tails so that it fits your mesh?

Comment: Thanks for reply! I did it once and it end up the situation at picture 2, I thinks is the shape of the hands is different, and it can't rig quite right.

Comment: Hard to tell what's happening, maybe share your file

Comment: it doesn't look like there's anything special here, as I said you need to make the armature fit the mesh, then parent again With Automatic Weight, it will need some manual corrections in Weight Paint mode though

Comment: Thanks man, I will try it out.